# Getting error like "syntax error at or near "TEXT"

Tags: python, postgresql, error-handling

Getting below error:

I am adding new column to postgresql

```
newColquery ='ALTER TABLE dwb_weekly_snapshot ADD COLUMN CT_ID data_type TEXT' 


  File "C:/Users/bz_dyadav/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/Scripts/dwb_update.py", line 24, in <module>
    result_dwb_snapshot = cursor.execute(newColquery)
  File "D:\python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pg8000\legacy.py", line 205, in execute
    raise cls(msg)
pg8000.dbapi.ProgrammingError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '42601', 'M': 'syntax error at or near "TEXT"', 'P': '60', 'F': 'scan.l', 'L': '1134', 'R': 'scanner_yyerror'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the documentation on `ALTER TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-altertable.html) the text ***`data_type`*** refers to your data type, not the literal word. It's in bold-italic meaning "placeholder name".

Easy fix:

```py
newColquery ='ALTER TABLE dwb_weekly_snapshot ADD COLUMN CT_ID TEXT'
```

Comment: Happens to the best of us.